# How can I edit numbers in my .txt file?

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter

I have code here and based on user input, I'd like to change the line of choice I will have selected. However, I can only currently temporarily change the line of text and when I write out the file again, the text had not overwritten permanently.

Here's my code:

```
public struct classMates
{
    public string first;
    public string last;
    public int ID;
}


static classMates[] readClassMates(classMates[] classMateInfo)
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\class.txt");
    int count = 0;
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        classMateInfo[count].first = sr.ReadLine();
        classMateInfo[count].last = sr.ReadLine();
        string idTemp = sr.ReadLine();
        classMateInfo[count].ID = Convert.ToInt32(idTemp);
        count++;
    }
    sr.Close();
    return classMateInfo;               
}

static void editClassMates(classMates[] classMateInfo)
{
    Console.Write("Who's number would you like to change? ");
    string classMateInput = Console.ReadLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < classMateInfo.Length; i++)
    {
        if (classMateInfo[i].first.Equals(classMateInput))
        {
            Console.Write("Enter new number: ");
            string temp = Console.ReadLine();
            int classMateNumber = Convert.ToInt32(temp);
            classMateInfo[i].ID = classMateNumber;
            Console.WriteLine("You have successfully changed {0}'s number to {1}.", classMateInfo[i].first,classMateInfo[i].ID.ToString());
        }
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    classMates[] classMateInfo = new classMates[43];

    listClassMates(classMateInfo);
    editClassMates(classMateInfo);
    listClassMates(classMateInfo);
}
```

I know  I am meant to use `File.WriteAllText()`, but I don't know how to utilize this snippet into my code.

Comment: It's not at all clear what problem you're having writing the file though, nor is `File.WriteAllText` a particularly obvious solution. I would probably start off writing a method to convert a `classMates` value into a string... As a separate matter, there are various issues with your code - such as using mutable value types, naming conventions, accessing a resource without a `using` statement or `try`/`finally` block. It would definitely be worth reading up on those issues.

Comment: You already know how to read the file.  Just write a method that writes the file and basically does the same thing.  But now using StreamWriter.

Comment: As said above, it only writes to the file temporarily. When I want to change their number, I input a new number and change the id  in the class.txt file. It's not permanently though.

Comment: @bsdu - only writes it temporarily? Uhhh... where? You're only doing `Console.WriteLine()` and changing the ID in `classMateInfo[i]` - that's not writing to a file... You should be writing to the file at the end of `editClassMates()`

Comment: Yes that is what I thought I was doing, I'm completely stumped as how I should be doing this though.

Comment: I need to replace a line in my text file with user input.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're expecting an easy answer but you actually require custom code that you need to think up yourself. 
If you're into LINQ and really want to use the `File.WriteAllText()` method you can use this oneliner i wrote for you, which I haven't tested:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\class.txt", string.Join(Environment.NewLine, (from cm in classMateInfo select string.Format("{1}{0}{2}{0}{3}", Environment.NewLine, cm.first, cm.last, cm.ID)).ToArray()));
```

Which creates a string array from your classMateInfo, concatenates the array using a newline as separator and write the entire string to the specified file.

Answer (score -2):

I don´t see you writing anything to a file.

```
Console.Write("Enter new number: ");
string temp = Console.ReadLine();
int classMateNumber = Convert.ToInt32(temp);
classMateInfo[i].ID = classMateNumber;
Console.WriteLine("You have successfully changed {0}'s number to {1}.", classMateInfo[i].first,classMateInfo[i].ID.ToString());
```

I should expect that you did something like:

```
rs.Writeline('foo');
```

But perhaps you need a streamwriter for that.